# Why am I encountering an error when trying to logout?

Tags: node.js, express, backend, ejs

I am creating a Meme web application. I have run into an issue where I am able to login, but when I try to logout I get a 404 error.
I am using ExpressJS with EJS template engine.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYhCL.png)

login.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        cb(null, { id: user.id, username: user.username });
    });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        return cb(null, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function verify(username, password, cb) {
    let usersArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../data/users.json')));
    let filteredArray = usersArray.filter(x => x.username === username);
    if (filteredArray.length > 0) {
        let usersData = filteredArray[0];
        if (usersData.password === password) {
            return cb(null, usersData);
        }
    } else {
        return cb(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password' });
    }
}));

router.post('/password', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/memes',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true  // Add this line for flash messages
}));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.user) {
        res.render('login', {user: null})
    } else {
        res.render('login', {user: req.user});
    }
});

router.post('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    req.logout(function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.redirect('/login')
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
var passport = require('passport')
var session = require('express-session');
var JsonStore = require('express-session-json')(session);

const memesDataModule = require('./memesData');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const memesRouter = require('./routes/memes');
const memeDetailsRouter = require('./routes/memeDetails');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'company logo')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist'));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new JsonStore()
}));
app.use(passport.authenticate('session'));


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/memes', memesRouter);
app.use('/memesdetails', memeDetailsRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I tried to add a get request for the logout, but it did not work. I just kept running into an error.

Comment: You're getting a 404 because whatever route you are trying to go to doesn't exist?

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)  (Because the image does not tell more than the text, so you could have posted just the text.)

Comment: note that you don't have a handler for route `'/logout'`, but for `'/login/logout'`. you should provide the code making the request if you want more help

Answer (score 0):

The code `app.use('/login', Router)` `in app.js` will prepend `/login` to all the routes defined in the Router.
Most likely the href attribute of the logout link is currently pointing to `/logout`. You should change the atribute value to `/login/logout` because you have matched the logout handler in your backend to the route `/login/logout`. Though `/login/logout` is really creepy. Instead you could change the `app.use('/login', Router)` to `app.use('/auth', Router)` so your logout link href attribute will point to `/auth/logout`.